# xaringan metropolis theme slide title font size

Tags: r-markdown

When using the `metropolis` theme in `xaringan` (RStudio 1.2.1070)

```
output:
    xaringan::moon_reader:
      css: [default, metropolis, metropolis-fonts]
```

I wish to have a smaller font for the title of each slide. If I use `h1` for a slide title i.e.

```
---
# The title of this slide

content
```

it works as expected, but if I try to use `h2` i.e.

```
---
## The title of this slide

content
```

the text appears in the body of the slide and not the banner.

Suggestions?

**Update**

Thanks for the prompt answer Martin. I modified your suggestion slightly.

Including:

```
.remark-slide-content.hljs-default {
  border-top: 40px solid #23373B;
}
```

adds the border to the title slide (which I didn't want).

For me, just adding this works fine:

```
<style>

.remark-slide-content > h1 {   font-size: 35px;   margin-top: -88px; }

</style>
```

Nevertheless, I must say my original question about using ## was prompted by the entry on `xaringan Presentations` in `R Markdown: The Definitive Guide` https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/xaringan-format.html where it states:

> **7.3.1 Slides and properties**
>
> Every new slide is created under a horizontal rule (---). The content
>   of the slide can be arbitrary, e.g., it does not have to have a slide
>   title, and if it does, the title can be of any level you prefer (#,
>   ##, or ###).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
---
title: Test
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [default, metropolis, metropolis-fonts]
---

<style>
.remark-slide-content.hljs-default {
  border-top: 40px solid #23373B;
}

.remark-slide-content > h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: -55px;
}

</style>

---
# The title of this slide

content
```

I guess you have to play around with the settings to achieve exactly the layout you want.

[image]

Comment: Well, the border is the banner you are talking of. So I thought you want it.