# How to control font size of header in xaringan slides?

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

I am using xaringan in rmarkdown with the following yaml heading.

```
---
title: "business"
subtitle: "investment"
author: "Instructor"
institute: "University"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [default, metropolis, metropolis-fonts, "styles_s4.css"]
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: arta
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
      
---
<style>
.remark-slide-content.hljs-default {
  border-top: 40px solid #23373B;
}

.remark-slide-content > h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: -85px;
}

</style>
---
# The Goods Market: Consumption

blah blah

---

# Remarks on Investment Decision

blah blah
```

But I always have a trouble squeezing my slide title on the top banner. In the following slide, I want to put "important remarks on investment decision". Any tip?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customize font size for all the slides in xaringan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53481699/customize-font-size-for-all-the-slides-in-xaringan)

Comment: And here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53130843/xaringan-metropolis-theme-slide-title-font-size

Comment: Thanks, yes, it does, but only problem is I got an extra empty page after the first title page. Any way to fix this issue?

Comment: How does it affect the empty page?

Comment: Once I add something like the following `<style>
...  font-size: 20px;...
</style>` it generates the empty slide after the first slide.

Comment: Hm, something flows. Can you add a reproducible example?

Comment: Sure, I just updated my post. Please see above.

Comment: @joe,  you are getting an empty slide, beacause you are adding  extra `---` below style tag.  Remove that and wrap that css code with code fence with `css` as done in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73247432/10858321